# What's the easiest way to export Google Analytics data automatically via JS?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to know whether it is possible to export my GA data automatically to a public URL, like a RSS feed. Then I can use JavaScript to fetch and show it, no need to authorize. I just don't want to write server side codes.

Thanks!

Comment: Presuming you ultimately show it in chart/table form, check out http://embeddedanalytics.com.  This is a service devised precisely to rid web publishers from having to learn the GA Export API.  All you do is authenticate once,  and place a snippet of code in your page where you want the chart to show.  (I work with the company).

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/) does this, but to my knowledge has no publicly consumable JSON API.

It might be possible with Yahoo Pipes according to the resources below:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2663700/94668
- http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2008-01-17-n73.html